# Choosing the entity while placing foreign key on 1-to-1 relations

Tags: database, foreign-keys, entity-relationship

"When transforming from Conceptual diagram (ER Diagram) to Logical Diagram (Database Model), the binary relations (1-to-1) is created by placing the primary key of one side as a foreign key on the other side."

So can someone explain to me how to choose which side's primary key to be placed to the which side's foreign key?

Answer (score 0):

In one to one relations either design will work. There is neither a parent nor a child.

You have to consider which side is Mandatory and which side is Optional. M-O to design and O-M design will work differently and one might be more preferable.

For example; If you have 2 tables for Computers and DVD-RW. Each computer can have 1 DVD-RW and every DVD-RW belongs to only one computer. So in this case it will be preferable to have computers table's primary key in DVD-RW table as a foreign key.